# I want to remove the value after *.*, but it the value of the length is not definite

Tags: sql, t-sql

Thank you in advance.

I want to remove the values after *.*, but the length is not defined it keeps changing but it should not take the values after the second FULL STOP.

1)Example:
 Input:- `ROL0602.E.DCM.5264403 and COK0105.F.SKE  and CLT005.02A.FCM.65721`

output:  `ROL0602.E  and COK0105.F and CLT005.02A`

2)  example : 
Input: `SKE-5700-00211-000`

output: `SKE-5700-00211`

These are the two columns i want some help with.

I tried using the charindex but as the length keeps on changing i wasn't able to do it.

Comment: why is `-000` removed in the second example? Thre are no full stops. Can the value ever have just 1 or less full stops?

Comment: @ Jodrell: the second example is another value i have to TRIM. it has hyphen and not full stop

Comment: I guessed that but, does it have anything to do with the question?

Comment: @Looking_for_answers Well, this is obvious. But what is the rule? Keep three parts?

Comment: @Looking_for_answers Please check my update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHnugo's solution is excellent but will fail if there is only one dot (.) in the string. Here's a tweaked version that will handle that (note my comments).

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('ROL0602.E.DCM.5264403'),('COK0105.F.SKE'),('CLT005.02A.FCM.65721'),('CLT099.02ACFVVV721'), ('SKE-5700-00211-000');

SELECT 
  CASE 
    --If there are two or more dots(.) then return everything up to the second dot:
    WHEN LEN(YourValue) - LEN(REPLACE(YourValue,'.','')) > 1
      THEN LEFT(YourValue,CHARINDEX('.',YourValue,CHARINDEX('.',YourValue,1)+1)-1)
    ELSE YourValue -- if there are 1 or 0 dots(.) then return the entire value
  END    
FROM @tbl AS tbl;
```

Comment: @ Alan : thank you so much. can you please help me with 2 example.

Answer (score 4):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('ROL0602.E.DCM.5264403'),('COK0105.F.SKE'),('CLT005.02A.FCM.65721'),('SKE-5700-00211-000');

SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',YourValue)>0 THEN LEFT(YourValue,CHARINDEX('.',YourValue,CHARINDEX('.',YourValue,1)+1)-1)
                                            ELSE YourValue END    
FROM @tbl AS tbl
```

The result

```
ROL0602.E
COK0105.F
CLT005.02A
SKE-5700-00211-000
```

Please provide a rule for the last example. Don't know how to cut this...

This command uses `LEFT` to take a string starting at the beginning. The lenght is found by searching for a dot, starting at the position 1 after the first dot.

### UPDATE: A more generic solution

The following fill first split the string in its parts (easy to use with other separators too). This is finally re-concatenated depending on a rule you can define yourself:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('ROL0602.E.DCM.5264403'),('COK0105.F.SKE'),('CLT005.02A.FCM.65721'),('SKE-5700-00211-000');

 WITH Parted AS
 (
    SELECT YourValue
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(tbl.YourValue,'-','.'),'.','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Casted
          ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',YourValue)>0 THEN '.' ELSE CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',YourValue)>0 THEN '-' ELSE '?' END END AS SeparatorChar
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
 )
 ,SingleParts AS
 (
     SELECT SeparatorChar
           ,YourValue
           ,ISNULL(Casted.value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'') AS Part1
           ,ISNULL(Casted.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)'),'') AS Part2
           ,ISNULL(Casted.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)'),'') AS Part3
           ,ISNULL(Casted.value('/x[4]','nvarchar(max)'),'') AS Part4
           ,ISNULL(Casted.value('/x[5]','nvarchar(max)'),'') AS Part5
     FROM Parted
)
SELECT CASE SeparatorChar 
        WHEN '.' THEN Part1 + '.' + Part2
        WHEN '-' THEN Part1 + '-' + Part2 + '-' + Part3
        ELSE YourValue
       END
FROM SingleParts
```

The result

```
ROL0602.E
COK0105.F
CLT005.02A
SKE-5700-00211
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try as follows:

```
SELECT  REPLACE('ROL0602.E.DCM.5264403',
                ( '.' + REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE('ROL0602.E.DCM.5264403'), 0,
                                          CHARINDEX('.',
                                                    REVERSE('ROL0602.E.DCM.5264403')))) ),
                '')
```